# HTML form action goes to wrong place, doesn't send variables to intended file

Tags: php, html, forms, apache

so I've been fighting with this for a few days, and I just can't seem to make it work. Whenever I press the submit button, the browser should send the post variables to write.php, but instead, it just redirects back to the website homepage, or the Document Root. This should be really, really simple, and I've done it before, but now it doesn't work for me. What I want to know is if this is a problem with my webserver setup, or PHP, or just a stupid mistake on my part. It's just a simple HTML form, not really special, so here's the form itself, in index.php:

```
<p style="font-size:13px">
<?php
$rp = fopen('mainlog.txt', 'r');
while(!feof($rp))
{
$read = fgets($rp);
echo($read).('<br/>');
}
fclose($rp);
?>
</p>

<form action="write.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="user" /><br/>
Changes:<br/>
<textarea cols="70" rows="8" name="change" style="background-color:#555;color:#ccc;font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Add Entry"/>
</form>
```

And here's where it send to, in write.php:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('mainlog.txt', 'a');
$wr1 = $_POST['change'];
#$my_t = getdate(date("g"));
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$date = date("n").('/').date("d").('/').date("Y").(', ').date("g").(':').date("i").(':').date("s");
$who = $_POST['user'];
$write = $date.(' by ').$who.('
').$wr1.('
');
fwrite($fp, $write);
fclose($fp);

header('Location: http://www.zennixstudios.com/first/chlog/');
?>
```

I have tried this both on my Apache 2.2 dedicated server with PHP 5 on FreeBSD8.2, and on XAMPP for Windows, with the same results. I have a suspicion that it may have something to do with PHP, specifically PHP include(), because I have several of those on this page, and when I put this on a friend's computer with XAMPP, but without the included files, the include()s just put errors on the screen, but the HTML form suddenly works fine. So, are there any known conflicts with HTML forms and certain PHP functions?

Other Notes:
The code shown above for index.php is within the main page div, but if you want the whole page source just ask. 
I'm pretty sure the error isn't in write.php, because I KNOW that the browser never sends anything to it, because it would at least put the date in mainlog.txt. 
If you want to see what this looks like in context, go to http://www.zennixstudios.com/first/chlog/

Thanks,
Chaos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
<table align="right"><tr><td align="right"><form action="/" method="post">Username: <input action="login.php" type="text" name="uname"/><br/>Password: <input type="password" name="passwd"/><br/><input type="submit" value="Login" align="right"/></td></tr></table>
```

You never closed the form up in your header for the username and password, so your `<form action="/" method="post">` is being used for pretty much the entire page and your `write.php` form action is being ignored because a form is already, technically, open. You'll need to close the form in your header for the rest of your page to work properly.

To reiterate: nothing is being redirected, you're actually posting all the data from both 'forms' to the location `/` as specified.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much! I wouldn't have seen that for a while, since I don't use that login field. I put that in a while ago, then couldn't find a reason to have a login system at all, so i just left it there... Anyway, Thanks Again!